# Windows Network Load Balancing not balancing load

Tags: windows-server-2003, wlbs

We have a performance test environment that we built to run load testing on. We have a presentation tier and an application tier each made up of 4 servers, with a sql server feeding these.

We are using Windows Load Balancing on Windows 2003 Server (Enterprise).

The issue I have is that the most of the time, during a test, about 80% or more (sometimes 100%) of the work is done by only one of the servers in the cluster.

Cluster operating mode:

- List item
- Unicast
- The host Port rules are:
- Protocols: TCP
- Filtering mode: Multiple host
- Affinity: None
- Load weight: equal.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update: 16/09/2010**
Thanks for the info [Bart Silverstrim](https://serverfault.com/users/13647/bart-silverstrim). I think what I am doing wrong is the fact that in our performance test environment, for the specific test that I am running, I only have a single client.

Is there any way that I could set up Windows Load Balancing on Windows Server 2003 to still balance the load while using only a single client? Basically, I just need it to round-robin.

Thanks

Gineer

Answer (score 2):

According to the NLB Fundamentals FAQ ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738464%28WS.10%29.aspx ) it doesn't balance CPU or memory usage, but rather network load and availability (kill a server, another one takes over).

Maybe that's what you're running into?